# JSON - and PHP - using Password - Is Answered

Tags: php, json

**Question:** Trying to PULL JSON data from a password protected json document.

PS: I know user and password is default value. Im not giving away my user info :).

Edit: I changed the Code. Now it shows a working one with or without solution. First code fetch data. Second code to display data on Website (in HTML).

This Code FETCH data from URL:

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$url = 'https://www.mysportsfeeds.com/api/feed/pull/nhl/2017-playoff/scoreboard.json?fordate=20170416';

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$nhl=json_decode($result,true);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

This Second code displays data in HTML :

Use a " `<?php include 'sports-json.php'; ?>`" in the Index site to put the First Code in another file, like sports-json.php .

```
<?php foreach ($nhl['scoreboard']['gameScore'] as $game) {
         echo $game['game']['awayTeam']['Name'] . $game['awayScore'] . ' to '  . $game['game']['homeTeam']['Name'] . $game['homeScore'] . "\n";
    }
```

I use the code Myself in HTML in a Table:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($nhl['scoreboard']['gameScore'] as $game) {
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td><img src="images/used/sports/Untitled-3_13.png" alt="W3Schools.com" style="max-width:80%"></td>';
            echo '<td>' . $game['game']['awayTeam']['Name'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td class="bold"> ' . $game['awayScore'] . ' - ' . $game['homeScore'] . ' </td>';
            echo '<td>' . $game['game']['homeTeam']['Name'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td><img src="images/used/sports/Untitled-3_14.png" alt="W3Schools.com" style="max-width:80%"></td>';
        } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Result of Table Code: https://snag.gy/IrK3RO.jpg

Comment: What is the output of `echo $resp;` and `echo curl_error($ch);`

Comment: have you checked curl error ? OR getting data from api call ?

Comment: Cutsey comments that my Code is incorrect isn't , well i know my code is wrong. Im just trying to get it right and hope someone who know json can help me.

Comment: as per comment like @chris85 you can do that as well as you can also show us json format of response so may be we can help you

Comment: http://stephaniie.com/scoreboard.json <- json file.

Comment: i just wanna 1. print everything (to see that the function work) 2. make an array out of the elements to be used in html. Thats all :). Its also the first time i work with json file. I used xml for a week now. But thought of going over to json instead. So yeah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the same process as parsing XML once it is an array. Here's an example to get the score and team.

```
$json=json_decode($da_json,true);
foreach ($json['scoreboard']['gameScore'] as $game) {
     echo $game['game']['awayTeam']['Name'] . $game['awayScore'] . ' to '  . $game['game']['homeTeam']['Name'] . $game['homeScore'] . "\n";
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/780729

You can `print_r` or `var_dump` the `$game` to see what indices are available. Modify the `$json['scoreboard']['gameScore']` in the `foreach` if you need information higher up in the JSON object.

Comment: Output `$json` is it as you posted previously?

Comment: After `curl_close($ch);` add `var_dump($result);`. What's the response?

Comment: @Nancy No, the problem is you aren't using the right username/password so you don't get back JSON. See `HTTP Status 401 - Bad credentials`.

Comment: Same thing, what is the response of the curl? The issue IS that you aren't getting back JSON.